# Object Oriented Approach for a Supermarket Simulator

Tags: java, queue, object-oriented-analysis

[image]

I have been learning java and data structures in java lately. I am dealing with this problem , this would be the first sort of real program i will be coding up . Up to this point i have only wrote code for short algorithms and data structures. So i was kind of looking for guidance on how i can approach this step by step. I am not looking for any code as i don't learn by looking at other peoples codes rather i needed guidance in how i should approach such a problem ..ex. do i first determine which classes i need etc? So after surveying the problem i realize this problem can be made as detailed or complicated as we like but i am trying to keep it simple do the basic that is required. So the following is what i have gathered so far.

I need a Customer class that will include name, age, number of grocery items bought, and method for determining which queue to join(join the shortest queue).

I need a several Customer queues that are associated with "checkers" who take random time to process each customer.

I would need a supermarket class where all the interaction between the customer, the queue and the checker would take place.

I am confused as i don't know where to start at the moment and also right now i don't have a clear idea on how everything will come together. I would really appreciate if someone can provide me step by step guidance as to what i should do in which order. By doing so it will help me in the future when i write more code for other object oriented languages.

I highly appreciate all inputs and apologize if have asked anything inappropriate.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you need a main loop that repeats over and over and handles input and all entities you have (customers, groceries, etc.)

Since you want the supermarket class to manage your program, I would start with that.
You will then realize that you need a customer in your supermarket.

So create that class when you need it.

Then you will realize you need groceries.

So create that class when you need it.

Then you will realize you need to create the instances for these classes.
That would happen inside the supermarket in your case.

So far, nothing has been made 'viewable' and no interaction with the program is possible.
It creates customers themselves. Adds groceries to them (e.g. in an ArrayList property of the customer).

Then you will realize you need Ques.

So create them.

Time for each customer could depend on the number of items times a random factor.

Now you have your supermarket running. You should add debug logging that you can maybe turn off so you see what's happening.

Now, if you want, you can create something where you can view the supermarket's statistics or however you want to visualize.

Then, create the input for the user. Remember that you are running an infinite loop. You can ask for user input on each iteration. When input is present, react accordingly.

Now: fix bugs, add features, test, fix bugs, add features, test, ...

I hope this is a high-level overview that will help you get started.
Don't be afraid that your classes are to simple at the start. You can always add functionality to them at a later stage when the rough program is running.